# How to get multiple entry for a single ID and display in same row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new coder and learning R. I am trying to solve the following. I have a following list like

```
Id    Stage  Duration

xxi       S1     23

xxii      S1     34

xxiii     S2     21

xxi       S2     29

xxiii     S3     15

xxi       S4     10

xxi       S5     12
```

I want an output like

```
Id   FS  duration_FS  SS  duration_SS   TS   duration_TS   FS   duration_FS

xxi  S1           23  S2           29   S4            10    S5        12

xxii S1           34  NA           NA   NA            NA    NA        NA

xxiiiS2           21  S3           15   NA            NA    NA        NA
```

Request for help.

Comment: Can you please the further details like how you decide `FS`, `SS` etc.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan.. FS is first stage, SS is second stage. This is actually data from duration of a project. Here I am having a data like a project_id follows some stages of project phases. Example Id xxxi follows first stage as S1, second stage as S2, third stage as S4 so on.